# python: name resolution clarification?

Tags: python

I'm reading the python reference [name resolution](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/executionmodel.html#resolution-of-names), which reads

> A class definition is an executable statement that may use and define names. These references follow the normal rules for name resolution with an exception that unbound local variables are looked up in the global namespace.

Based on that, I would expect the following code

```py
x = 10

def f():
    x = 5

    class Test:
        y = x

    return Test

print(f().y)
```

to print `10`, however it prints `5`. is this a mistake in the reference, or am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: You set `Test.y` to `x` inside the function, where `x` is 5. `f()` returns `Test`, so `f().y` is `Test.y`, which is 5. Why were you expecting 10?

Comment: @khelwood: because it says that names unbound in the class definition block, are looked up in globals, contrary to the rules. what happens here seems to follow the standard rules

Comment: It says "unbound local variables are looked up in the global namespace". `x` is not an unbound local variable.

Comment: @khelwood: the way I understand this, it mean *unbound* in the context of class definition, not the function. Also, I don't see how the current behavior is an expection to the standard rules

Comment: A `class` statement cannot have its own local variables, because a `class` statement doesn't establish a new scope. It's a weird pseudo-scope, where `y` would temporarily shadow any "outer" `y` until the `class` statement completes, but would be ignored in the definition of any methods.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In this case, 'normal' rules apply:

```
x = 'global'

def f():
    x = 'defined in f'

    class Test:
        print(x) # not local, normal rules apply

f()
# defined in f
```

In this second case, we would expect an `UnboundLocalError: local variable 'x' referenced before assignment` if we were inside a function:

```
x = 'global'

def f():
    x = 'defined in f'

    class Test:
        print(x) # unbound local at this time
        x = 'assigned in Test'
        print(x)
```

But for the first `print(x)`, `x` will be taken from the global namespace:

```
f()
# global
# assigned in Test
```

Answer (score 0):

I think @khelwood gave the answer. The value in the variable:

> Test.y

is an integer that you define, but you never give the x = 10 to the function.

Maybe what you want is actually:

```
x = 10
def f(x=5):
    class Test:
        y = x
    return Test
print(f().y) #print default 5
print(f(x).y)
```

The last line print 10 since x is given to the function, and therefore the class set y as x

Answer (score 0):

You can see the exception by wrapping `f` in another function that defines a local variable `x`:

```
x = 10

def g():
    x = 7
    def f():
        class Test:
            y = x

        return Test
    return f()

print(g().y)
```

Now the output is 7, as the lookup of `x` in the `class` statement bypasses the local scope of `g` to find the global value of `x`.

In your code, because `class` establishes a new *namespace*, but not a new *scope*, the value of `x` is taken from the current local scope, that of `f`.